# Why am I getting two different results from two functions that don't seem different at all taking advantage of closures?

Tags: javascript

I've assigned the number 0 to a variable outside of a function. I'm using this variable to take advantage of closures because I've also created a simple function that returns the variable incremented solely for the purpose of keeping track of how many times I call the function. I call the function 5 times and finally pass the function invoked to the alert function. What's confusing is, if I increment the variable and then return the variable afterward, the alert message I get is "6" rather than "5" which is the number of times I called the function however, if I increment the variable and return it at the same time, meaning the variable incrementation is a part of the return statement, I get the correct number of times I've called the function in the alert message. Why am I getting different results? The variable outside of the function I'm using as my counter is assigned the number 0. The global execution context is created and holds this variable right? In addition to that, my 5 calls have created 5 execution contexts and each time, the new incremented variable lives and stays in memory for the next call to increment. Where is "6" coming from?
Here's my code that produces 6 as the number of times the function has been called:

```
var i = 0; 

function add() {
   i++;
   return i;
}

add();
add();
add();
add();
add();

alert(add());
```

By simply doing this:

```
  function add() {
   return i++;
  }
```

I get the correct number alerted.

Comment: you are calling add function again in  `alert` dear, why dont you alert `i`

Comment: @zan but why do I get the correct number when the incrementation is a part of the return statement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's related to incrementing flow.

Pre-increment (++i) adds one to the value of `i`, then returns `i`, in contrast, i++ returns i then adds one to it.
In first case you increment value in separate statement so, pre or post increment doesn't play any role, in second pre or post incrementation play role, because function firstly return `i` and than increment.

You would get same result in case if your function add would be the next

```
function add(){
  return ++i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In first case value is returned after incrementing, in second value is returned before incrementing

try `alert ( i );` rather than `alert( add() );` you will get the same value

Answer (score 0):

`return i++;` means you return i first and then do the increment.

By the way,

`return ++i;` means you do the incrementfirst and then return i.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling alert(add()), you are calling add() one more time and henece the value of i increment to 6 since current value of i is 5 as you have already called add 5 times. If you print i before add() call in alert its still 5 but as soon as you call add() in alert it becomes 6 because you are invoking method call.

```
    var i = 0;

    function add() {
        i++;
        return i;
    }

    add();
    add();
    add();
    add();
    add();

   // alert(i +' '+ add()); //5  6
    alert(add() +' '+ i); //6  6
```